# Help with the latest Redactor, removing formatting options

Tags: redactor, button, remove

In the past I've managed to remove a few formatting buttons from Redactor but am having trouble with the new version.

The goal is to remove 'quote', 'code' and 'heading1' from the formatting-dropdown. (see attached).

[image: I need to know how to remove the highlighted items]

So far I have tried various ways of inserting this [from the documentation](https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/formatting/change-formatting-dropdown/):

`['p', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5']`

This is the only attempt which hasn't resulted in a syntax error, but which has resulted in the formatting button disappearing completely!

```
  "buttons": [
    "html",
    "formatting: ['p', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5']",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "unorderedlist",
    "orderedlist",
    "link",
    "image",
    "video"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "fullscreen",
    "video"
  ],
  "linkNewTab": true,
  "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

Please could you spoon feed me the json as I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the buttons array, you should only mention formatting.

The actual styles you want to put inside an array with key "formatting".

```
{
  "buttons": [
    "html",
    "formatting",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "unorderedlist",
    "orderedlist",
    "link",
    "image",
    "video"
  ],
  "formatting": ["p", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5"],
  "plugins": [
    "fullscreen",
    "video"
  ],
  "linkNewTab": true,
  "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

Reading a bit further in the docs, you could also remove the styles you don't want, instead of stating the ones you do want:
`formattingHide: ["blockquote", "pre", "h1"]`

Comment: Bro, I love you!